# How to use rmarkdown to convert a dataframe to printable individual listings?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to use rmarkdown to transform a single dataframe into a printable set of individual listings, as in the phone book, but I'm stuck. How would I turn this dataframe:

```
df<-mtcars[1:4,1:4]
```

into a set of listings like this?...

```
Car: Mazda Rx4
MPG: 21.0
cyl: 6
disp: 160
hp: 110

Car: Datsun 710
MPG: 22.8
cyl: 4
disp: 108
hp: 93
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is very similar to JSON.  If we turn it into a JSON string, we can then clean out the characters you don't want.  This won't be ideal for large data sets

```
library(rjson)
library(magrittr)

df<-mtcars[1:4,1:4]

apply(df, 1, toJSON) %>% 
  setNames(paste0("Car: ", names(.), "\n")) %>% 
  gsub("(\\{|\\})", "", .) %>%  # Remove braces
  gsub(",\"", "\n", .) %>%      # replace ," with line break
  gsub("\"", "", .) %>%         # replace double quotations (could be problematic if you have text data with double quotes)
  gsub("[:]", ": ", .) %>%      # add a space after colons
  paste0(names(.), .) %>%       # put the name of the car above its data
  paste0(collapse = "\n\n") %>% # bring them into one string
  cat()
```

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df<-mtcars[1:4,1:4]
df<-cbind.data.frame(car=row.names(df),df)
row.names(df)<-NULL

text<-gsub( '[][{}?*\\,    \\"]', replacement = "", text)
cat(gsub("\\:", ": ", text))

car: MazdaRX4
mpg: 21
cyl: 6
disp: 160
hp: 110


car: MazdaRX4Wag
mpg: 21
cyl: 6
disp: 160
hp: 110
```